# Customize download-bar in popular browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox

When someone tries to download a file, the browser displays a small bar at the bottom of the screen with the text RUN or SAVE. This can be hard to notice for some users.

Is there any way to make it more visible by using html/css?

Comment: No, thats how the browser vendors decided to do it and it can't be customized by the webpage.

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify the bar of course, but what you can do is append a (for example) dark translucent overlay onto the screen when the download link is clicked. The download bar will remain on top, giving it a kind of "highlighted" effect. Then set a timeout for the overlay to fade away.

The standard solution is to bring the user to a page that explains what to do. See here: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/#download-fx